# trouble with npm preinstall script

Tags: npm, pnpm

I'm trying to make the jump to pnpm from npm.  I found a helpful hint to keep from running "npm install" after I make the change as described here: https://pnpm.js.org/en/only-allow-pnpm

Unfortunately my preinstall lifecycle override doesn't get executed.  Seems to simple enough but npm install still works when I run something like "npm install @types/jest"

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "react-sandbox",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "preinstall": "npx only-allow pnpm"
  }
}
```

npm version 6.14.2.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately, the `preinstall` script is executed only during argumentless installation. So when you run `npm add @types/jest`, that script will not be executed, thus npm won't be prevented from running.

But it will fail when running `npm install`.

As of now, there is no other way to prevent npm from execution.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I confirmed what you said.  I was hoping for a more comprehensive safeguard, although I'm not sure how critical that protection is.  I'll move forward with giving pnpm a try.

Comment: Yarn's maintainer tries to solve this issue by pmm. Let's hope it will be merged to NodeJS https://github.com/arcanis/pmm