# How can I throw an error if someone tries to install a package in a repo that uses Yarn (and does not want NPM used)?

Tags: node.js, npm, yarnpkg

The repo that I'm in uses Yarn. The team wants to only use Yarn. Is there some way to enforce that? I want any `npm install [packagename]` to error out.

It seems that [preinstall](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63165630/trouble-with-npm-preinstall-script) only runs for `npm install`, not `npm install [packagename]`.

Thought these would work (which I got from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61911013/30946)), but they don't:

```
$ node --version
v14.18.3

$ cat package.json | grep "preinst"
    "preinstall": "echo 'preinstall' && npx only-allow@1.1.0 yarn &&  rm -rf packages/hub-app/node_modules/@nutrien",

$ cat package.json | grep -A 4 "engines"
  "engines": {
    "npm": "no-npm-only-yarn",
    "yarn": ">=1.22.16 <2",
    "node": ">=14.18.3 <15"
  },

$ npm config get engine-strict
true

$ npm i lodash.isempty # <--- this line should error
⸨      ░░░░░░░░░░░░⸩ ⠧ loadExtraneous: sill resolveWithNewModule @azure/abort-controller@1.0.4 checking installable status
```

Comment: Hi yeh. Its a bug in npm. The trick with engines only works for a straight "npm install" and not "npm install package-name". NPM incorrectly does not check engines for the latter.

Comment: hoping for a workaround

Comment: I am having this issue: running `npm i` and `npm install` without a package and it still runs the install process.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Force yarn install instead of npm install for Node module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41076172/force-yarn-install-instead-of-npm-install-for-node-module)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61911013/30946 -- what I ended up using. Not really an answer to this question, but close enough for my needs at the time.

Answer (score -2):

The closest I could get was https://stackoverflow.com/a/61911013/30946. So the question suggested as a duplicate isn't a duplicate per se, but the answer there is close enough to an answer for my needs.

Comment: The usual protocol when another Q/A answers the question adequately is to close as a duplicate rather than posting an answer like this that's just essentially a link without any additional info. So it'd probably be best to either delete this answer and close as a duplicate, or update the answer to be complete in itself and say what you had to change from the other answer to solve it.

Comment: That answer doesn't **actually** answer this question, it's only applicable some of the time.

Comment: I will delete this answer when an actual solution is presented. As such, this answer works some of the time but fails for an important use case: `npm install foo` when the repo prefers `yarn add foo`